# packages intstall problem

Tags: bibliographies

```
GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
Date: 2024-01-03 08:19:21
MiKTeX: 2.9.7140
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 22631
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: D:\latex for gyanu\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheck: not yet
LastUpdate: not yet
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: D:\latex for gyanu
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: D:\latex for gyanu
UserConfig: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Invokers: non-existing/explorer

Warning: the following problems were detected:
  1: Never checked for updates.

ERROR DETAILS
Program: D:\latex for gyanu\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console.exe
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\RestRemoteService.cpp:245
Error: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Could you please include additional information in your question to help others to answer? For instance, what steps are you doing to cause this error to appear? Have you attempted anything to fix the error, and if so, what happened then?